# compile learning-opencv (O'Reilly) code

Tags: opencv, compilation

my platform is ubuntu16.04
opencv version: 2.94

when I use "make" command to compile LearningOpencv_code,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvD9z.png)

Please tell me how to solve the problem. Thanks!

Comment: "opencv version: 2.94" -- that's probably [not right](http://opencv.org/releases.html).

Comment: How have you installed OpenCV ?